# Cannot redisplay Windows Form after closing it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

When I click a button a form is opened, but if the form is already open, then the app should display the message "Form already open!" and do nothing else.

My problem is, once I close the window [x] I can't open the form again.

Here's the code:

```
Form2 decript_form = new Form2();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!decript_form.Visible)
          decript_form.Show();
     else
          MessageBox.Show("Form already open!");
}
```

Comment: You could override the close event handler and instead hide the form

Answer (score 2):

When the "Close" button is pressed, you want it to just "hide" the form...you need to use `e.Cancel` to stop it going on and closing.

If you really really want to close the `Form2` window instead of hiding it while your application is running....then call `ReallyClose`....so that the close isn't prevent (then create a new `decript_form` or `null` it out).

(Alternatively `decript_form.Dispose()` would force real closure too)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private bool m_bReallyClose = false;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_bReallyClose)
        {
            this.Visible = false;

            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    public void ReallyClose()
    {
        m_bReallyClose = true;

        this.Close();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 decript_form = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!decript_form.Visible)
            decript_form.Show();

        else
            MessageBox.Show("Form already open!");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decript_form.Dispose(); // or .ReallyClose();
        decript_form = new Form2();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your code, however, the problem remains, if I try to re-open the form with the button tells me: Unable to access a deleted object

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you talk about the [x] on Form2 being pressed. It that's the case you should handle the Closing event in Form2() and add

```
 this.Hide();
```

to the handler. Even a closed window is still 'shown' until it is hidden.

```
class Form2
{
     override protected void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
     {
          Hide();
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the [x] on form2. where I have to add this.Hide() ?

Comment: @PietroAriano i've changed my answer to give you a more detailed explanation